# CosmosDb string search on numeric

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have fields in my CosmosDb that are in numeric value (example a zipcode), and I would like to include them in a string search.
I haven't seen on the [Syntax help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference#bk_built_in_functions) (or anywhere) how to do it..

Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Keywords))
    {
        var keywords = filter.Keywords.ToUpper().Split(' ');

        foreach (var keyword in keywords)
            query = query.Where(o => (o.Data.General.Dossier.ToUpper()
                                      + o.Data.General.OrderId.ToUpper()
                                      + (o.Team.Name ?? "").ToUpper()
                                      + (o.Data.General.MaintenancePlant ?? "").ToUpper()   
                                      + (o.Data.Location.BoxNumber ?? "").ToUpper()
                                      + (o.Data.Location.City ?? "").ToUpper()
                                      + (o.Data.Location.HouseNumber ?? "").ToUpper()
                                      //+ o.Data.Location.Zip.ToUpper()
                                      + (o.Data.Location.Street ?? "").ToUpper())
                .Contains(keyword)  );

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just add `o.Data.Location.Zip.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(keyword)` to your search?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException: 'Method 'ToString' is not supported.' first thing i tried :)

Comment: Oh, too bad ;-)

Comment: What is the type of `query`? How is it initialized?

Comment: my query is this : _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>($"/dbs/{_databaseId}/colls/{CollectionId}");

Answer (score 0):

Note: `o.Data.Location.Zip.ToUpper()` won't compile. You're doing `ToUpper()` on a numeric type.

You can do this (preferable to use `StringBuilder` when amending strings):

```
var query = query.Where(o =>
                           new StringBuilder()
                           .Append(o.Data.General.Dossier)
                           .Append(o.Team.Name)
                           .Append(o.Data.General.MaintenancePlant)
                           .Append(o.Data.Location.BoxNumber)
                           .Append(o.Data.Location.City)
                           .Append(o.Data.Location.HouseNumber)
                           .Append(o.Data.Location.Zip.ToString())
                           .Append(o.Data.Location.Street)
                           .ToString()
                           .ToUpper()
                           .Contains(keyword));
```

Keep in mind that this `Where` will return `IEnumerable<typeof(o)>`.

Comment: This would be the exact same problem. .ToString() is not supported by the provider.

Comment: @Tom Any solution for this